# Event after all new mails has been loaded [Outlook Add-In - C#]

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am currently programming an add-in for outlook in C# and I am searching for an event, which is getting raised after all new incoming mail items has been loaded. [enter image description here][1]

I could understand it well, so I took a screenshot, to help you orientating. I mean an event which is getting raised after all boxes (e.g. "Outbox" is synchronized").
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFAZW.png

Thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SyncObject.SyncEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobject.syncend) event is fired immediately after Microsoft Outlook finishes synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send/Receive group.